# Formula for $(i,j)$-th cofactor

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and denote by $M_{ji}$ the $(j,i)$-th cofactor of $A$, namely $(-1)^{i+j} \det A[ij]$, where $A[ij]$ is obtained from $A$ by deleting the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. Does it hold that
$$M_{ji} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n, \sigma(i) = j} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \, A_{1 \sigma(1)} \cdot \dots \cdot \hat{A}_{ij} \cdot \dots \cdot A_{n \sigma(n)},$$
where the hat means omit that factor? Of course
$$M_{ji} = (-1)^{i+j} \sum_{\tau \in S_{n-1}} \text{sgn}(\tau) \, A_{1 \tau(1)} \cdot \dots \cdot A_{n-1, \tau(n-1)};$$
since each sum contains $(n-1)!$ terms, I tried to construct a correspondence between $\tau$ and $\sigma$ for which the associated summands coincide:
$$\sigma(k) = \begin{cases}
    \tau(k) &\quad \text{if} \quad {k < i, \tau(k) < j}\\
    \tau(k-1) &\quad \text{if} \quad {k \ge i+1, \tau(k-1) < j}\\
j &\quad \text{if} \quad {k =i} \\
\tau(k)+1 &\quad \text{if} \quad {k < i, \tau(k) \ge j} \\
\tau(k-1)+1 &\quad \text{if} \quad {k \ge i+1, \tau(k-1) \ge j}.\\
\end{cases}$$
However, determining $\text{sgn}(\sigma)$ in terms of $\tau$ is a nightmare, so I'm not quite there. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: the sign is $(-1)^{|Inv(\sigma)|},$ and if you see $\tau$ and $\sigma$ have the same sign except for the inversions that depend on the position $i,$ so $sgn(\sigma)=sgn(\tau)(-1)^{|\{(a,b):a=i\vee b=i\}\cap Inv(\sigma)|}.$ From there i would say that you should partition $S_n$ in groups that fix the sign and the ones that do not fix the sign in order to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You can define an index mapping function

$$M_n(m):=\begin{cases}m<n\to m\\m\ge n\to n+1\end{cases}$$ and write the formula for the determinant of the $n-1\times n-1$ matrix

$$B_{kl}:=A_{M_i(k)M_j(l)}.$$